# Como procurar um nome com struct

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um código que vai receber os nome de 5 pessoas e o 3 presentes que ela levou para festa, e depois vai ser pedido o nome da pessoa e o presentes que ela trouxe para festa, e mostrar se existe ou não, só que quando eu tento comparar, nunca encontra o nome, mesmo o nome estando na lista.

Aqui está o meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define pessoas 5
#define pre 3

 struct p
 {
   char nome[100];
   char presentes[3][100];
 };


  int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    struct p convidados[pessoas];
    char teste[100], pesquisa[100];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < pessoas; i++)
    {
      setbuf(stdin, NULL);
      scanf("%s", convidados[i].nome);
      for(j = 0; j < pre ; j++)
      {
         setbuf(stdin, NULL);
         scanf("%s", convidados[i].presentes[j]);
      }
   }
   setbuf(stdin, NULL);
   scanf("%s %s", teste, pesquisa);
   for(i = 0; i < pessoas; i++)
   {
     for(j = 0; j < pre; j++)
    {
         if(strcmp(convidados[i].nome, teste) == 0 && 
   strcmp(convidados[i].presentes[j], pesquisa) == 0)
         {
            printf("Nome encontrado:\n");
         }
         else
         {
             printf("Nao\n");
         }
     }
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesquisa que tem está correta mas a forma como mostra o valor encontrado não, porque tem um `printf` para cada `presente` que analisa. Em vez disso o que quer fazer é guardar numa variável se encontrou o que procurava e apenas no fim dos dois laços/ciclos apresentar o resultado ao usuário:

```
int encontrado = 0;
for(i = 0; i < pessoas; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < pre; j++) {
        if(strcmp(convidados[i].nome, teste) == 0 &&
                strcmp(convidados[i].presentes[j], pesquisa) == 0) {
            encontrado = 1;
        }
    }
}

if (encontrado == 1){
    printf("Nome encontrado:\n");
} else {
    printf("Nao\n");
}
```

Pode também tornar o código mais eficiente colocando `break` nos dois `for` caso a variável `encontrado` já seja `1`, pois nesse caso já encontrou logo não precisa de pesquisar mais.

```
for(i = 0; i < pessoas; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < pre; j++) {
        if(strcmp(convidados[i].nome, teste) == 0 &&
                strcmp(convidados[i].presentes[j], pesquisa) == 0) {
            encontrado = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (encontrado == 1) break;
}
```

[Veja como funciona no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ByhKnb)

<sup>Tornei o array mais pequeno para ser mais facil de testar</sup>